# A view that is both add/edit (and urls to support) to essentially do an update_or_create in django

Tags: django, django-views

So I want to use the update_or_create.  This is what my view looks like but it doesn't feel right...

EDIT Updated code

URL Pattern:

```
  url(r'^businessinformation/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', BusinessInformationUpdate.as_view(), name='business_information_update'),
```

URL Usage:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'ipaswdb:business_information_update' 1 %}"> Edit Business Information</a></li>
```

Rest of the code

```
class BusinessInformationUpdate(UpdateView):

  model = BusinessInformation
  form_class = BusinessInformationForm
  template_name = 'ipaswdb/business_information/business_information_form.html'        
  success_url = '/ipaswdb'

  def get_object(self):
    pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    obj, created = BusinessInformation.objects.update_or_create(
      pk=pk, defaults={'businessName': 'Your Special Business', 
        'business_address_line_one':'100 Great Job Lane', 
        'business_city':'Anywhere',
        'business_state':'Your State',
        'business_zip':'00000',
        'business_phone':'555-555-5555',
        'business_fax' : '555-555-5555'
      })
    return obj




  def form_valid(self, form):                                                                                                     
    self.object = form.save()
    print(self.object) # prints the right changed value just never makes it back to the db?!

    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
```

Comment: You could probably answer your own question by making the view you are talking about and testing it. And yes, you can use default info if the value you are looking up is not found.

Comment: updated question to be clearer i think

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this implementation will work. Because it should throw error when it tries to fetch the object from DB if its not created(in `get_object` method). So, if you can override that instead like this:

```
class BusinessInformationUpdate(UpdateView):
    ...

    def get_object(self):
       pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
       obj, created = BusinessInformation.objects.update_or_create(
        pk=pk, defaults={'businessName': 'Your Special Business', 
                'business_address_line_one':'100 Great Job Lane', 
                'business_city':'Anywhere',
                'business_state':'Your State',
                'business_zip':'00000',
                'business_phone':'555-555-5555',
                'business_fax' : '555-555-5555'
       })
       return obj
```

And don't need to override the `get_context_data` method.

Comment: I get no errors, the form comes up with the default data.  It IS saved to the database, but only the default data.  It doesn't seem to let me edit it, makes no saves after that.   Edited the response above to show the url pattern and how I call the url to show how I get to the form